R GT Table with tooltip seems to leave a bit of HTML
I have been trying to add conditional tooltips in gt tables for ages and I think I have almost cracked it.  However I am getting a silly "> appear in my row.  I have tried replacing it but that doesn't seem to work.  So nearly there, any ideas what is is causing this.  I think it might be a HTML thing.
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  col_name = c("Example 1",
               "Example 2",
               "Example 3",
               "Example 4"))
df |>
  gt() |>
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "lightcyan"),
      with_tooltip(NULL, "This is a piece of explainatory text
that explains what is happening or significant
within the highlighted box")
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = col_name,
      rows = parse_number(col_name) > 2
    )) |>
  text_replace(
    pattern = '">',
    replacement = " ",
    locations = cells_body(columns = col_name)
  )

Example of issue
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)
Matrix products: default
locale:
1 LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8
time zone: Europe/London
tzcode source: internal
attached base packages:
1 stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
other attached packages:
1 lubridate_1.9.3 forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.1   dplyr_1.1.4     purrr_1.0.2     readr_2.1.5
[7] tidyr_1.3.1     tibble_3.2.1    ggplot2_3.5.1   tidyverse_2.0.0 gtExtras_0.5.0  gt_0.11.1
[13] iheatmapr_0.7.1
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
1 sass_0.4.9            utf8_1.2.4            generics_0.1.3        NHSRplotthedots_0.1.0
[5] xml2_1.3.6            fastcluster_1.2.6     stringi_1.8.4         hms_1.1.3
[9] digest_0.6.37         magrittr_2.0.3        grid_4.4.1            timechange_0.3.0
[13] RColorBrewer_1.1-3    fastmap_1.2.0         jsonlite_1.8.9        rematch2_2.1.2
[17] fansi_1.0.6           scales_1.3.0          cli_3.6.3             rlang_1.1.4
[21] munsell_0.5.1         withr_3.0.1           tools_4.4.1           tzdb_0.4.0
[25] colorspace_2.1-1      paletteer_1.6.0       vctrs_0.6.5           R6_2.5.1
[29] lifecycle_1.0.4       htmlwidgets_1.6.4     fontawesome_0.5.2     pkgconfig_2.0.3
[33] pillar_1.9.0          gtable_0.3.5          glue_1.8.0            xfun_0.48
[37] tidyselect_1.2.1      rstudioapi_0.16.0     knitr_1.48            htmltools_0.5.8.1
[41] compiler_4.4.1

I cannot reproduce this issue, for me the cells render just fine. Maybe you want ot add the output of sessionInfo, such that we know which version you are using?

You can use text_transform

library(gt)
library(gtExtras)
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  col_name = c("Example 1",
               "Example 2",
               "Example 3",
               "Example 4"))
df |>
  gt() |> 
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = col_name,
      rows = parse_number(col_name) > 2
    ),
    fn = function(x) {
          lapply(x,\(y)with_tooltip(y,"arbitrary tooltip"))
    }) |> 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "lightcyan")),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = col_name,
      rows = parse_number(col_name) > 2
    )) 


Thanks, that does the job.  With tab_style version the whole cell became the link to the tooltip and I didn't have the blue underline as a hyperlink, which I think is prettier.  But this certainly hits the spot.  Thank you!
